# Through-The-Door population, translation

Tags: traducción

I'm a beginner in this language and I want to translate the phrase "Through-The-Door population" into Spanish. The context is the following:
Credit scoring models are usually developed using the accepted Known Good-Bad applicants, called KGB model. Yet, the KGB model does not represent the entire Through-The-Door population

In Spanish:

Los modelos de puntaje de crédito generalmente se desarrollan utilizando los solicitantes aceptados, (conocidos buenos y malos), llamado modelo KGB. Sin embargo, el modelo KGB no representa a toda la población a través de la puerta.

That sounds like funny "población a través de la puerta".
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "modelos de calificación crediticia" for "credit scoring models". The phrase "conocidos buenos y malos" is wrong: it should be "buenos y malos conocidos".

For "through-the-door population" I'd suggest "solicitantes de crédito".

[Here](https://www.scoreplus.com/papers/glossary) is a definition of "Through-the-door population":

*All the applicants for any particular credit or financial product irrespective of the final accept/reject decision. Sometimes abbreviated to TTD population.*

My translation would be as follows:

Los modelos de calificación crediticia por lo general se desarrollan a partir de / sobre la base de los solicitantes aceptados (buenos y malos conocidos), modelo denominado "KGB" por su sigla en inglés. Sin embargo, el modelo KGB no representa a todos los solicitantes de crédito.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Al buscar por internet pareciera que al expresión "Through-the-door" se refiere a la acción de una persona ir a un banco y "pasar por la puerta" para solicitar algo, por ejemplo un crédito y parece estar en oposición a las solicitudes de crédito gestionadas por personal o agentes que salen a ofrecer créditos. Alguien tiene algo sobre el origen de esa expresión?

Answer (score 0):

In Spanish we do not have an idiom equivalent to "through the door population", you can probably say ***la gente que entra por la puerta*** ("people who cross the door"), but it would be incomprehensible in the context.

I think you should translate it properly as ***el universo de solicitantes*** ("all of applicants").

Comment: I like "universo". Even if "universo" is an all-embracing term, I think it needs to be reinforced as "todo el universo de los solicitantes" or "el universo completo de los solicitantes" to unequivocally include applicants of all sorts.